# Win32 API, Get Child Windows for Game

Tags: c++, vb.net, winapi, bots

I'm using [this code](http://jtech-online.com/?p=307) to get the child windows of all open processes.

The code itself is working correctly, I get a 2 dimensional list of handles. Each index has a list of handles to the child windows of a specific process.

I'm trying to get a child window of a game. The game itself is inside window. It appears in the **task manager** and in my **task bar**. There is a button inside the game I press that opens a new window. The new window does **not** appear in the **task manager** but it does appear on the **task bar**.

The problem is the code in the link above will not return any child windows for the game even though a new window has opened and it can be seen in the task bar.

Any Ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok found the solution, should have used GetWindowText instead.